# Is there an easy solution to implement a 403 render strategy in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-view

I set up a simple ACL Module as controller plugin. Now I would like to implement a "403 render strategy" so that for "deny" I just set a 403 response and the "error/403" view from the template_map will be rendered. The functionality should like the original 404 strategy.

I've taken a look at the `Zend\Mvc\View\Http\RouteNotFoundStrategy` but found it a little bit overweight. Is there a simpler way to do so?

Comment: Did you look into BjyAuthorize ( https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/ ) before asking this question? It's quite complete and provides you with a decent unauthorized strategy...

Comment: @Ocramius yes, I did. It's quite nice and I think it will solve the problem. But may be there is another (smaller) solution? Like in ZF1 - there you can just change controller and action in request and the 403 will be raised.

Comment: In ZF2, application exceptions can be handled via listeners attached to one of the `Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_*_ERROR` events of the `Zend\Mvc\Application`'s event manager. A simple closure would work too:

    `$app->getEventManager()->attach('dispatch.error', function () {
        die('application error!');
    );`

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at [SlmErrorException](https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmErrorExceptions), of which I am the author of. It allows you to throw exceptions which are marked with an exception interface. This interface determines whether a 40x or 50x status code will be set and which error template will be rendered.

You can create your own exception

```
namespace MyModule\Exception;

use SlmErrorException\Exception\UnauthorizedInterface;

exception UnauthorizedUserException
    extends \Exception
    implements UnauthorizedInterface
{
}
```

Then you throw the exception somewhere in your code and the module checks if the thrown exception implements any of the known interfaces. Then a status code will be set (so in this case, 403) and the view `error/unauthorized` will be rendered.

This module is in development and not ready for production. But you might have a look and see if it fits. Perhaps you can help contributing stabilizing and help writing tests so more people can use this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without using third party modules.

You can create a custom event that when triggered will set the template to the desired one (please reed the code comments):

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $eventManager->getSharedManager()->attach('custom', '403', function(MvcEvent $event) use($eventManager){

        //set the 403 template you have previously prepared
        $viewModel = new ViewModel();
        $viewModel->setTemplate('error/403');

        $appViewModel = $event->getViewModel();
        $appViewModel->setTemplate('layout/layout');//set the default layout (optional)
        $appViewModel->addChild($viewModel, 'content');//add the 403 template to the app layout

        //prevent the MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH to fire by calling it
        //with high priority (100) and using $event->stopPropagation(true);
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, function(MvcEvent $event) {
            $event->stopPropagation(true);
        }, 100);
    });
}
```

And then you can trigger this event from anywhere in the code:

```
$e = new \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent();
$eventManager = new \Zend\EventManager\EventManager('custom');
$eventManager->trigger('403', $e);
```